# APNS rejects with reason - "DeviceTokenNotForTopic"

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip

As i can see already many questions raised for this same problem, still i was not able to resolve this issues.

In our apple developer account we have created, both have same bundle ID

1. Apple push service certificate and p12 file
2. VOIP certificate and p12 file

Both are uploaded in client server side. When they tried do incoming call, the shared this logs with DeviceTokenNotForTopic

**[token=b7c3d4fd47a7275e798df99a53babf4e6fa56f4e4f29deafb73a18, payload={"fromNumber":"58","callId":"1fe30312c9e5d7ca2e","date":"2023-03-03T07:32:52Z","aps":{"alert":{"title":"Incoming Call"}},"fromUser":"Concierge B","event-name":"voip-incoming-call"}, invalidationTime=null, priority=IMMEDIATE, topic=null, apns-collapse-id=null], success=false, rejectionReason=DeviceTokenNotForTopic, tokenExpirationTimestamp=null]**

I have revoke the VOIP certificate and created new one and deplaoyed that p12 in client server side. Should i need to create new apple push service certificate as well ?

Not sure why apns reject when both bundle ID are same .

Any help would be great !

Comment: Are you running a Xcode build or a TestFlight build or a build installed from the App Store?  Are you using the sandbox or production push endpoint?  For an Xcode build you need to use the sandbox endpoint. For the other two builds you need to use the production push endpoint.

Comment: @Paulw11 We using testflight build. Same clients also testing from itestflight only. And its an production endpoint .

Comment: The error indicates that you have a device token for a different nfironmwnt (in this case a a sandbox token)

Comment: @Paulw11 How do i recheck this, Because i have the production provisioning profile to upload the build to testflight. And using production APNS certificate

i.e How do i check that this token si from sandbox or production one. Also i have an certificate , in that how can i check this is belongs to sandbox or production one

Comment: @Paulw11 I have compared the certificate it an Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) only

Comment: The device token is the token that you would have stored in your database that you receive in the app delegate `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications`. So you need to ensure that the token you have stored for the user is the token that was received when they used the TestFlight build.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have created two apple push services. Ons is sandbox and another one is production one. I can able to see the diffreance in keychanin between this two. So the uploaded one was production one only

Comment: This is nothing to do with the push services or the certificates. It is to do with the device token you tried to send the push to. The error says that the device token either isn't for this environment or not for your app bundle.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your quick response. But this was working before, so i was not able to differentiate or identify the device token with this enviroment or bundle ID

Comment: @Paulw11 This is basically an VOIP incoming call issue

Comment: No, it is an invalid device push token issue. It either doesn't match your bundle id or environment.